# strtok is returning null but not the printf

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, strtok

I am trying to initialize a linked list from a .txt file using `strtok()`.

But when I want to initialize the name (the first element of my structure) strtok returns a "(null)".

However when I `printf()` my `strElement` I get the expected name.

heals.c

```
#include "heals.h"

ListeHeals* initHeals()
{
    ListeHeals* ListeHeals = malloc(sizeof(*ListeHeals));

    char const* const fileName = "items/heals.txt";
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r"); 
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Fichier non ouvert");
    }
    char line[256];
    const char * separator = "|";
    int count = 0;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        char* strElement = strtok (line, separator);
        while (strElement != NULL) {
            Heals* heal = malloc(sizeof(*heal));
            if(count == 0)
            {
                printf("%s\n", strElement);
                heal->name = strElement;
            }
            else if(count == 1)
            {
                heal->heal = atoi(strElement);
                ListeHeals->first = heal;
            }
            strElement = strtok (NULL, separator);
            count += 1;
        }
      count = 0;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return ListeHeals;
}

void printListeHeals(ListeHeals* ListeHeals)
{
    if (ListeHeals == NULL)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    Heals* actual = ListeHeals->first;

    while (actual != NULL)
    {
        printf("Nom : %s\n", actual->name);
        printf("heal : %d\n\n", actual->heal);
        actual = actual->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}
```

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhtKO.png)
The first line is my printf.

Here is the file heals.txt :

```
Potion de vie I|30
Potion de vie II|80
Potion de vie III|200
```

The heal structure (heal.h):

```
#ifndef heals_h
#define heals_h
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct  Heals
{
    char* name;
    int heal;

    struct Heals* next;
};
typedef struct Heals Heals;

struct ListeHeals
{
    struct Heals* first;
};
typedef struct ListeHeals ListeHeals;

ListeHeals* initHeals();
void printListeHeals(ListeHeals* ListeHeals);

#endif
```

The output I expect:

```
nom : Potion de vie I  // I have (null)
heal : 30              // I already have it
```

Any help is welcome thank you!

Comment: What are the other 2 lines then? If `strtok` would return `NULL` on the first token, how would you enter your `while(strElement !=NULL` loop at all`? I assume you mess up your loops or something else outside the code you show. Please show your input (content of the file), the output and the expected output. Together with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You seem to read multiple fields of `heal` from 1 line of the file but you allocate memory for a new element on each token within a line. That looks weird but your code is too incomplete to judge.

Comment: The 2 others lines are the print of the heal object

Comment: my input file is : 

Potion de vie I|30

Potion de vie II|80

Potion de vie III|200

Comment: Here is all my code called by the main.c

Comment: that is all my code

Comment: I'm confused about `heal->name = strElement;`  If `heal->name` is a `char *` then you are pointing it into the local `line` array which goes out of scope at the end of the function - then you can't use `heal->name` later in your program.  ``heal->name` should probably be a character array and you should use `strcpy` to put the string into it.

Comment: You should run your program in a debugger and single step through it. I would guess you have lots of errors but `strtok` is OK. You never link the nodes of your list to another nodes. You just insert as `first`. Also you allocate 2 structs per line. Then you never reset `count`. Besides that you should copy the strings instead of assigning pointers.

Comment: It looks like you are using variable `count` to determine which field is being handled by the current iteration of the inner loop, but in that case (1) your implementation is broken, because it doesn't reset `count` for each new line, but also (2) that's needlessly complex.  Since you want separate code for handling each field anyway, it would be shorter and much clearer to get rid of `count` and that inner loop altogether, and just extract and process the expected fields one after the other in the body of the outer loop.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are allocating a new `Heals` for each field instead of one per line.  Each one created has only one of its members initialized.

Comment: ok yes my program is not fully ended but that should work for the first element right? i reset count now and that changes nothing

Comment: Reseting count alone does not help. See my answer

Comment: For now i dont care about the linked list side of the program but why it dont work for the first name?

Comment: The node holding the name never gets enqueued into your list. As a result you cannot print it lateron.

Comment: Did you retry my solution?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems and you are doing things more complex than needed.

Most importantly:

1. You do not enqueue your nodes into your list.
2. You do not reset `count` for each new line. This means you will not handle the name for any other line.
3. You do not allocate memory for your strings but only assign pointers into your `line` buffer. That will go out of scope when the function is done.
4. As you allocate new nodes for each token you will end up with one node holding the name and one node holding the other value.

---

Update:
Why did this cause the result you got?
You allocate one node for the name but do not enqueue it in your list.
Then you allocate another node. This node does not hold the name but only the second value. This node goes into the list.
When you print the content of your list you will only find the second node.

Also you overwrite the head of your list with any new node without linking them together.

Therefore you will only get 1 node in your list, no matter how many lines you read.
And this node will only hold the `heal` value.

---

A fixed version could look like this (untested):

```c
ListeHeals* initHeals()
{
    ListeHeals* ListeHeals = malloc(sizeof(*ListeHeals));
    // TODO: Check for NULL

    char const* const fileName = "items/heals.txt";
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r"); 
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Fichier non ouvert");
        // TODO: return with some error indication. You mustn't continue the function.
    }
    char line[256];
    const char * separator = "|";

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        char* strElement = strtok (line, separator);
        if (strElement != NULL) {
            Heals* heal = malloc(sizeof(*heal));
            // TODO: Check for NULL

            // Handle the name
            printf("%s\n", strElement);
            heal->name = malloc(strlen(strElement+1);
            strcpy(heal->name, strElement);

            // Handle the value
            strElement = strtok (NULL, separator);
            // TODO: Check for NULL

            heal->heal = atoi(strElement);

            // enqueue node into front position
            heal->next = ListeHeals->first;
            ListeHeals->first = heal;
        }
        else
          printf("invalid file content: %s\n", line);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return ListeHeals;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser I post an anwser down with the output, i didnt have the numbers and that reverses the linked list.

Comment: That answer does not solve all possible issues. As you already stated earlier, the list part was not in focus. If you want to preserve the order from the file you must reverse the list afterwards or write a function to enqueue at the tail of the list.

Comment: I had a copy&paste error in second call to `strtok`. Try again

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here, most of which @Gerhardh has already detailed in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69745379/2402272).  But the one that actually causes the problem you asked about is

4. You create a new `Heals` on each iteration of your inner loop, set a value for only one member of each one, and assign each as the head of your list.  Thus, when you get around to printing, the `Heals` at the list head (that being the only one then in the list) has had only its `heal` member set, not its `name` element.  A different `Heals` gets the corresponding name set, but that one is then leaked.

It looks like Gerhard's revised code fixes that, too.  Even though they didn't enumerate this particular issue, their more natural implementation approach isn't prone to making such mistakes.

Answer (score -1):

I tried and that output this :

```
Potion de vie I
Potion de vie II
Potion de vie III
Nom : Potion de vie III
heal : 0

Nom : Potion de vie II
heal : 0

Nom : Potion de vie I
heal : 0
```

Comment: Why it didnt came with the numbers?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should not post an answer if it does not answer the question. You should delete it.